# How do I fetch data from this Schema please?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Kindly help me map out my data from this array. I have been able to fetch and store in state. I can also view on postman but it is not coming on my frontend when i use .map(). Kindly teach me what to do. I am new with this .

Thanks and regards

Every data is stored on connectReqs. I can view on Postman and on my console.

Sometimes, I get an error that it cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FProfile')

```
const [connectReqs, setConnectReqs] = useState([])
```

**Profile Schema**

```
friendshipStatus: [{
     FProfile: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "profile"
     },
     connectStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        ref: "status"
     },
},
],
```

I am currently mapping this way. I have all the data stored in state

```
{connectReqs.map(function (connectReq) {
return (
{connectReq[0].friendshipStatus[0].FProfile.lastname}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If **connectReqs** is the array containing all the data (as you've said), then.

```
const lastNames = connectReqs.map((cr)=>({cr.friendshipStatus[0].FProfile.lastname}}))
```

I'm not sure about the whole model you have, but I think **cr[0]** or **connectReq[0]** (as you've done) is what you're doing wrong.
As .map() iterates over the array one by one.